# How to exclude variants with repetitions on Python?

Tags: python, hash

It is necessary to iterate over the hash function without repetition. 4 repetitions in a row are allowed.

```
for i in itertools.product('0123456789abcdef', repeat=64):
 b = (''.join(i))
 print(b)
```

The product iterator starts sorting through all possible options. But I'm wondering how you can get rid of a lot of unnecessary options with a lot of repetitions, that is, you just have to skip these options. 4 repetitions in a row are allowed.
for example, this option is allowed

```
00009f15677b4d67b5262c6b2413b49f8cfab4b3e1e5d5ab766a922a28106b1e
```

And this is not allowed

```
00000f15677b4d67b5262c6b2413b49f8cfab4b3e1e5d5ab766a922a28106b1e
```

At the same time , the position of the repetitions does not matter

Comment: Iterating over `itertools.product` with those arguments is a recipe for disaster. That loop is going to run 16^64 times. That's a 77-digit number. If you want to do something smarter, you'll need to implement it yourself, not use the blunt hammer that is `itertools.product`. But even with your "no more than four repetitions" restriction, you still have an iterable that you will never exhaust in the lifetime of the universe.

Comment: i agree with @SilvioMayolo . so the question here is more: what are you really trying to achieve? enumerating a subset of hash function outputs alone is not very useful... and where does that restriction come from? the output of a hash function is basically an integer. imposing constraints in hex seems a bit arbitrary.

Comment: We take any hash function, then run it through the hashing algorithm and get some result. The task is to find the prototype of the hash function with the condition.

Comment: what difference do you make between 'hash function' and 'hashing algorithm'? and what is the *it* you 'run through the hashing algorithm'? what do you call a 'prototype' here? and why is is subject to a condition? please give an example input and an output of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: For example, we have such a random hash function. f6253a2172ec61eb962a159923c995eedaee1fe04552f8d67ca00f8ef6cef947 is our prototype.
and output
a422cfb44fbf97e94889202b877f5b43c9a05cf1a70b5971c54995d1d2656492
The task is to find the prototype, knowing only the way out and that's all. And repetitions must be excluded so as not to waste time, because the probability of repetitions is very low with random generation. If you think I'm an idiot, then I'm not! For finding the prototype, I will receive from 500k to 1m dollars.

Comment: "prototype"? do you mean pre-image? then: good luck with that! the 1m dollars would not start to cover your energy bill for that. not even considering the time that would take.